# Скрывающийся текст

Tags: html, css

Скрыл текст при под фото при помощи opacity а как его теперь отобразить при наведении на само фото а не только на этот невидимый текст.

html

```css
.blockMan {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  }

ul.hr1 {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

ul.hr1 li {
  width: 14%;
  margin-left: 126px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  order: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.summary {
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.hr1 li:hover,
  .summary:hover {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockMan">
  <ul class="hr1">
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/dauni.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/kris.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/skarlet.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/tor.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: вынести `img` из `p`, чтобы картинка и текстовый блок были на одном уровне вложенности (оборачивать `img` в `p` незачем имхо) и прописать `img:hover + .summary {opacity: 1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.blockMan {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  }

ul.hr1 {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

ul.hr1 li {
  width: 14%;
  margin-left: 126px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  order: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.summary {
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.hr1 li:hover .summary {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockMan">
  <ul class="hr1">
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/dauni.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/kris.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/skarlet.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
    <li><p><img src="/home/evgeniy/Рабочий стол/test 2/img/tor.jpg" alt="" /></p><p class="summary"><b>text text<br>text</b><br>text texttext texttext texttext text</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло!